# Angularjs Factory is undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angular js, now I am trying to use factory to make code clearer. But now I am getting the following error:

> $injector:unpr(Unknown provider).

I stuck here and cant find where is the problem. Service and this controller were in different files actually, then I tried to put them together, but still it doesnt work. I will be very glad if you will help me to find out my problem.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.factory('AuthenticationService', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){

var currentUser;

return {
    login: function(username, password){
        var endPoint = "http://localhost:8080/RestServer/main/just/Authorize";
        var jsonData = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

        $http.post(endPoint, jsonString,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).success(function (data,status, headers ){

            if(data.access == "ok")
            {
                $location.path("learning");
            }
            else
            {
                $location.path("error");
            }

        });
    },
    logout: function(){},
    isLoggedIn: function(){},
    curUser: function(){return currentUser}
};
}
]);
app.controller('loginController',['$scope', 'AuthenticationService',      function($scope, AuthenticationService)
{
    $scope.login = function()
    {
        AuthenticationService.login($scope.username, $scope.password);
    }
}]);
```

Here is html:

```
 <html data-ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/services.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/controllers.js"></script>
 <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Welcome!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main" ng-view="">

 </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added

Comment: can you copy the full error starting from $injector:unpr(Unknown provider) error.

Comment: You are missing ng-controller in your html.

Comment: @ippi I am using ng-route :) Sorry I forgot to add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `$scope` from your factory, You don't typically use $scope inside a factory, service or provider,also add `$http` as a dependency since you are making a $http call

```
app.factory('AuthenticationService', [ '$location','$http', function( $location,$http){
}
```

Here is the working [`Application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FUSD4LyETI4itmfBtwK?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I very beginner in Angular JS. It helped me :)

Comment: My reputation is too low. It is written that I need 15 reputation at least

Comment: @NikhanbayevNursultan for accepting as answer you dont need 15 reputation, just click the tick mark

Comment: Oh I found it. Done. Once again thank you very much!